# Whats the most efficient way to build a FULL FLS perm set?

Tags: profile, permission-sets, field-level-security

View All / Modify All system perms in no way interact with FLS. Yet there's also no convenient system permission to say 'this user should have read/edit ability for all field FLS', as far as I know.

Via UI the only way I'm familiar is clicking into every object on a profile/perm set... then clicking on every. single. field's. checkbox.

It's like a new movie in the *Saw* series. They hate us. They actually, really really hate us. They don't want us to be happy.

Or am I missing something easier? Do I need to write some complex code to query every field on every object, parse the results write it into a perm set XML file in order to grant permission? Do I need to spend 20 hours clicking through our hundreds of objects and thousands of fields, updating the perm set every time there's new fields added?

Is Salesforce profile/perm control an elaborate fever dream of Baal, lord of demons?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch back to classic and use some free [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-admin-check-al/efcahpjiijlbojmfmaceicchnhkgdkje?hl=en) which gives an option to check all.

[image]

This might save you a lot of time. Only problem is you have to perform this activity for each and every object you want to give access.

Comment: Thanks Sanket, better than nothing